# battery charging icon issue

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I have come across a problem today which hasn't occurred before. The adapter was plugged in but it wasn't on the percentage as I wanted to be at.

So I removed the adapter for a while and then replugged.

However, from that time, while the battery is charging, the icon on the bottom right of the screen  doesn't move up and remains same after 3-4 moveups.

How am i supposed to solve this?

Comment: Well, first you have to install an operating system.  I'd suggest Windows, since it's quite comfortable with that bug.

Comment: How old is the battery?  Have you tried running it without the charger to see how long the charge lasts (whether the battery is actually only partially charged or the indicator is wrong)?  What type of battery is it (NiCad, NiMH, Lithium)?  Do you always keep it fully charged and run on the adapter or do you regularly run it on the battery and run the charge down?

Comment: its Lithium ion battery for my MSI-CX 61 notebook. The battery is truly getting charged. The issue is the indicator which ceases after 3-4 fills on the battery icon located on the system tray which takes place on the right bottom of my screen.