# Battery drained after a few hours of charging

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

I seem to have a serious issue. I still have the 'visual indication not moving up after a few ticks' [battery charging icon issue](https://superuser.com/questions/821073/battery-charging-icon-issue). But there is another problem which is way more critical.

I can not find the balance of the charge with the battery from the 2 months after I purchased the laptop.

Yesterday, I charged the battery till it completed. Again, I have launched the laptop this morning and what I notice is 96%.

Most people explained that its acceptable from the point 95% and above but I wonder why the battery is drained "even if I shut the PC down and remove the adapter" before putting it into sleep mode.

Do you know how to cope with this?

Answer (score 3):

Source [Sleep and hibernation: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions)

> **Will sleep eventually drain my laptop battery?**
>
> Sleep requires an extremely small amount of power. If your laptop
>   battery charge gets critically low while the computer is asleep,
>   Windows automatically puts the laptop into hibernation mode.

Source [How Much Battery Life Does Sleep Mode Really Drain?](http://lifehacker.com/5526542/how-much-battery-life-does-sleep-mode-really-drain)

> We measured our portable computers' battery use while sleeping, and with a full shutdown and startup, across a range of thumbnail time periods—one hour, two hours, then four, eight, 12, and, in one test, 24 hours. In all cases, actively open programs were shut down before a sleep or shutdown.

Here is one of the graphs (there are others in the article) showing battery loss over time when sleeping:

[image]

[BatteryCare](http://batterycare.net/en/index.html) is a free program for Windows that can help to monitor and calibrate your battery. See the link for more information.

Also take a look at [Proper laptop battery usage guide](http://batterycare.net/en/guide.html) on the same site.